# Non-rectangular meshgrid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, control-systems, optimization

I want to create a non-rectangular meshgrid in matlab.

Basically I have a polygon shaped feasible set I need to make a grid of in order to interpolate 3D data points in this set. The function for interpolation is given and requires finite (x, y, z) inputs. Where x is nx1, y is 1xm and z is nxm. Right now I have the mesh set up with linspace and set all NaN (infeasible) values to 0 before using my function, which is wrong of course (third figure).

Is there a simple solution for this?

I added a picture illustrating what I'm currently doing: First plot is the feasible set, second plot are solved sample data points in this set and third plot is the interpolation (currently still with rectangular meshgrid and NaN = 0).
What I need is a meshgrid looking like the first figure (red polygon) instead of a rectangular one. In the third plot you can see that the rectangular meshgrid in combination with setting NaN to 0 (=infeasible values, not included in the red polygon set) results in a wrong interpolation along the edges, because it includes infeasible regions.

[image]

Comment: As more of a pure programming question this might be more suited to https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yeah I thought it kinda fits here because Matlab is heavily used in DSP and my use case here is explicit model predictive control.

Comment: Normally, your interpolation method should support NaNs and outpit NaNs as well where relevant. That's what NaNs are for. Can you tell us what function you are using?

Comment: Yoi can also assign nans to your outpit where you consder you grid invalid. Something like output(isnan(mygrid)) = nan;